# Redirect to exacly same path with diffrent languge

Tags: php, query-string

Here is what I'm trying to do:

Whatever page customer open script will redirect him to his preferred language read from `$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"];`

example:
Customer browser is set in Spanish. If he open page `http://example.com/script-name.php?param1=aa&param2=bb`

than script will redirect him to `http://example.com/es/script-name.php?param1=aa&param2=bb`

I have script which provide me with language of the browser `$lang=substr(Get_Client_Prefered_Language(),0,2);` that is sorted

Than I have script which reads the address

```
$location = '';
parse_str(html_entity_decode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']),$query_string);
if(isset($query_string['language'])) {$query_string['language'] = null;}
$new_query_string = !empty($query_string) ? http_build_query($query_string) : '';
if($new_query_string != ''){$location .= '?'.$new_query_string;}
```

and that provide me with new address:

`$location="https://macrohosting.co.uk/".$lang.$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"].$location;`

and than I can use `header('location: '.$location);`

All works quite well but some of the pages I have already url rewrited.

And not sure how to adjust above script so when customer visit  `http://example.com/page1.htm` than will be redirected for example to `http://example.com/es/page1.htm`

Without that modification customer is redirected to `http://example.com/es/page_example.php?param=aa&param=bb`

Comment: What webserver do you use for rewriting? Apache or Nginx?

Answer (score 0):

there is no need for you to redirect user for each request . it's the worth way to handle the problem.

you can get user browser language in front controller (for example index.php file) and then generate links accordingly.

you are trying to hit your web server 2 times for each request?? it's not an option.

if you are using a php framework there should be a better way to handle the problem.

```
    <?php
    $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    $link_to_about_us_page = "http:://domain.com/$lang/about";
```

and keep in mind that first parameter after domain in every request is language and according to that language you should fetch content from your storage and show data.(this part should be handled by your router)

and if language is not provided you redirect users to your default language .
for example

```
http://domain.com/contact
```

to

```
http://domain.com/en/contact
```

thats how drupal handle multilingual. there are multiple things that can affect content language (user browser| url | user ip | ...)

and you can arrange priorities.

Comment: You are right I should do that only for the first link customer customer opens. Probably store language in session? The script is used as an hook in WHMCS. I just need to solve my problem first.

Comment: read here if seo is important to you 
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en
 and also store user language in session is not a bad idea but make sure your URL is different for each language . thats what google says for seo.
for example
domain/en/blabla
domain/fr/bleble

Comment: thanks mhndev I'm already using all suggestions from this page. My page is already rewrited to be http://example.com/es/page.php I just want to solve the redirection problem.

Comment: I already handle language so if you go to ``http://example.com`` you will see english version and if you go to ``http://example.com/es/`` you will see spanish version and etc..  My question is about something else.

Comment: its not a standard way to server static pages multilingual.
all you have to do is url rewrite for one url and that's index.php
just like all php frameworks.
don't invent the wheel we have so many multi lingual options for php.
almost all frameworks handle it very well don't implement it from the base.
just use a php package.

Comment: I can't use any well know php framework. I'm doing this for WHMCS which is mostly ioncube encrypted so there are not many files you can modify. As default WHMCS switch languages over session and cookies. I had to change this and I'm already handing language switching as per Google advice. My question is about detecting and redirecting. Each customer need to be redirected only once. At the time when will open website for the first time.